# Retrieving image in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to read/retrieve an Image from excel file to PHP using PHPExcel.
This code is used to retrieve a value from a particular cell.

```
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B5')->getValue();
```

This retrieves only the cell value, But i cant retrieve a image. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Effectively, images are __overlaid__ over the cells rather than in the cells, so you can't use getCell()->getValue() to get the image, only the actual content of cells. See DaveRandom's answer for accessing the actual images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Googling `phpexcel read image`](http://www.google.com/search?q=phpexcel+read+image) yielded [this page](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/257231) as the second result. It tells you how to do this.

To quote the relevant info directly:

> `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection()` 
>   will return an ArrayObject of all the image objects in the active worksheet.
>
> These objects will be either `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing` or `PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing` objects: you can identify which using [`is_a()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php). You can then use the methods appropriate to that class (as described in the API) either to read the image data from file (for `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing` objects) or directly from the `PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing` object itself. The `getName()` and `getDescription()` methods can be used to retrieve the relevant values from the image object.
>
> Note that it's also possible to have image objects associated with print headers:
>
> `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->getImages()`  can be used to retrieve images from the header/footer. This is an array of `PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooterDrawing` objects. All the `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing` methods can be used to extract the image file from these objects.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the images from a row. I have a sheet with multiple rows and multiple columns with image. So, I would like to iterate them in row basis. Please advice me. Thanks..

Answer (score 6):

Check this example. I found it useful ..

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']);

$i = 0;
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );

        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $extension = 'png';
    } else {
        $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(),'r');
        $imageContents = '';

        while (!feof($zipReader)) {
            $imageContents .= fread($zipReader,1024);
        }
        fclose($zipReader);
        $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
    }
    $myFileName = '00_Image_'.++$i.'.'.$extension;
    file_put_contents($myFileName,$imageContents);
}
```

**Source:** http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/18189

Answer (score 0):

```
class ExcelImport
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $excel;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $work_sheet;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $excel_data = [];
    /**
     * ExcelImport constructor.
     * @param Request $request
     * @throws \PHPExcel_Exception
     * @throws \PHPExcel_Reader_Exception
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        //Load file from request
        $this->excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($request->file('file'));
        //Get active sheet
        $this->work_sheet = $this->excel->getActiveSheet();
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function import()
    {
        //Iterate through drawing collection
        foreach ($this->work_sheet->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
            //check if it is instance of drawing
            if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing) {
                //creating image name with extension
                $file_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $drawing->getName()).'.'.$drawing->getExtension();
                //Get image contents from path and store them in Laravel storage
                Storage::put('public/'.$file_name, file_get_contents($drawing->getPath()));
                //create images array initially
                $this->excel_data[] = [
                    'image' => $file_name
                ];
            }
        }
        //Map other data present in work sheet
        return $this->rowData();
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    private function rowData()
    {
        $i = 0;
        //Iterate through row by row
        foreach ($this->work_sheet->getRowIterator(2) as $row) {
            //iterate through cell by cell of row
            foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
                //In case of image data that would be null continue
                //We have already populated them in array
                if(is_null($cell->getValue())){continue;}
                //Map other excel data into the array
                $this->excel_data[$i]['name'] = $cell->getValue();
            }
            $i++;
        }
        //Return final data array
        return $this->excel_data;
    }
}
```

**source (my blog):** https://meramustaqbil.com/2019/02/23/how-to-extract-images-from-excel-file-using-maat-websites-laravel-excel/

Comment: Based on the blog post you've linked being authored by someone with the same name as your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/blog. If you do so, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose that it's your own site, it's considered spam.  See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [self-promotion in the help center](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).