# Get Image position (cell) in excell using php

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Hello fellows I have the following excell file:
[image]

And I want using Php Excell library to instert the data on the database. But the problem is how I will know each image (marked with a number) will represent a specific product.

I need something to determine the position on the image cell wize. How can I do that?

EDIT1:
The images are embeded in excell.

EDIT2: On how to get the images I have seen it on: [Retrieving image in PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887332/retrieving-image-in-phpexcel#7888644) . But the problem is on determining the position of the image.

Comment: If the image is not embeded, and the image's url represent the product number ie \\server1\img\product101.jpg you may be able to grab the image's url.

Comment: Nope the image IS embeded in the excell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already found the answer that loops through the image collection to extract individual images as drawing objects:

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    ....
}
```

Each of those individual `$drawing` objects has a `getCoordinates()` method that returns the cell address for the top-left corner of that image. The drawing will be positioned relative to the top-left corner of that cell.

It's slightly more complex, because the image may be offset from that position: the drawing object's `getOffsetX()` and `getOffsetY()` methods will tell you the offset from the top-left corner of the cell; but normally these values are close enough to zero to assume that the cell coordinate is accurate.